# Firestore responding with "cannot find 'cards' in scope"

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, mvvm, swiftui

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f6u3AnOKZd0) to get data from firestore and changed what i needed to correspond to my model but it keeps responding with "cannot find 'cards' in scope" and I'm not sure what i did wrong. (i think i got the mvvm labels right)

**VIEW**

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestingView: View {

@ObservedObject private var viewModel = CardViewModel()

var body: some View {
    List(viewModel.cards) {
        Text(cards.name)
    }
    .onAppear() {
        self.viewModel.fetchData()
    }
  }
}
```

**VIEW MODEL**

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class CardViewModel: ObservableObject {
@Published var cards = [Cards]()

private var db = Firestore.firestore()

func fetchData() {
 db.collection("cards").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
  guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
    print("No documents")
    return
  }
  self.cards = documents.map { queryDocumentSnapshot -> Cards in
    let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
      let name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
      let pronoun = data["pronoun"] as? String ?? ""
      let bio = data["bio"] as? String ?? ""
      let profileURLString = data["profileURLString"] as? String ?? ""
      let gradiantColor1 = data["gradiantColor1"] as? UInt ?? 0
      let gradiantColor2 = data["gradiantColor2"] as? UInt ?? 0
      let gradiantColor3 = data["gradiantColor3"] as? UInt ?? 0
      
    return Cards(name: name, pronoun: pronoun, bio: bio, profileURLString:   profileURLString, gradiantColor1: gradiantColor1, gradiantColor2: gradiantColor2, gradiantColor3: gradiantColor3)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**MODEL**

```
import Foundation

struct Cards: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
    var pronoun: String
    var bio: String
    var profileURLString: String

    var gradiantColor1: UInt
    var gradiantColor2: UInt
    var gradiantColor3: UInt

    var profileURL: URL {
        return URL(string: profileURLString)!
    }
 }
```

Comment: What you are doing is redundant.  You already create a guy named 'querySnapshot.'  You then create another snapshot.  What is that for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List` will provide an element to its trailing closure -- see `card in` in my code. Then, you can access that specific `card` in your `Text` element.

```
var body: some View {
    List(viewModel.cards) { card in //<-- Here
        Text(card.name) //<-- Here
    }
    .onAppear() {
        self.viewModel.fetchData()
    }
  }
}
```

I'd suggest that you might want to rename the `struct Cards` to `struct Card` since it is *one* card. Then, your array would be `@Published var cards = [Card]()` -- ie an array of `Card`s. From a naming perspective, this would make a lot more sense.

Comment: had a feeling it was something simple like that.

i do have another question, i have a seperate struct that uses the profile url to generate a profile picture to the main view. Im not sure how to add that to the KFImage without using a for each or a list

Comment: Sorry, but it’s not clear from just that amount of information. Could be a good topic for a new question though.